# I want to launch mainframe session configured through IBM Personal Communications. Please advise, how to launch using tosca

Tags: mainframe, tosca

I want to launch mainframe session-PComm through TOSCA  but couldn't find much documentation on TRICENTIS website.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily launch a session by using the "TC Start Program" module - you can find it in the Aidpack (if you don't have it, you can download it from the [support portal](https://support.tricentis.com/community/top_downloads.do)).

For actually automating a terminal emulator session you would use the [Host Engine](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.0.0&url=classic_engines/host/installation.htm).

Hope this helps!

Michael